# IndexError: Target 60972032 is out of bounds

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to call cross entropy loss but it says the index is out of range

```py
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
target = torch.empty(128, dtype=torch.long)
result = loss(output, target)
```

Note the output has the shape `torch.Size([128, 10])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `target` tensor from provided example is not initialized, see [torch.empty](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html#torch-empty)

It's empty, to fix that use, for example, `.random_` method, like in [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#crossentropyloss) docs example:

```py
...
target = torch.empty(128, dtype=torch.long).random_(10)
...
```